# Какие бывают flow архитектуры процессоров?

Tags: архитектура, процессор

Читал статью на хабре по dataflow архитектуре и там было упоминание про то что современные процессоры строятся по controlflow архитектуре, но в гугле про controlflow ничего найти не удалось. Где можно почитать про controlflow архитектуры и какие ещё бывают flow архитектуры?

Comment: смотря по какому критерию сравнивать.

Comment: [Data flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_architecture), [Control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow). По запросу _data flow and control flow in computer architecture_ в гугле находятся pdf с описанием.

Comment: Кстати, а почему dataflow пишется слитно а control flow раздельно? Как будто первое термин а второе не понятно что.

Comment: Второе -- это традиционная Фон Неймановская архитектура (вроде как *проза* на которой говорят все (в отличии от *поэзии*))

Comment: По поводу разных потоков можно  почитать [тут](http://www.nsc.ru/win/elbib/data/show_page.dhtml?77+861)